# How can I get total number of devices and total number of messages send to azure IoT hub c#

Tags: c#, azure, c#-4.0, iot, azure-iot-hub

we only have these two methods available for azure IoThub in c#.

```
Device device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync("deviceId");
```

and

```
device = await registryManager.GetDevicesAsync("max count");
```

but how to get all available device count or active device count and also a messages count using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **number of devices** can be retrieved by using a [device query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language), e.g.:

`SELECT COUNT() AS numberOfDevices FROM c`

which returns something like this:

`[
  {
    "numberOfDevices": 123
  }
]`

To retrieve the **number of messages** you need to connect to the Event Hub-compatible endpoint, connecting to each underlying partition and looking at each *Partition Info* (*Last Sequence Number* and *Sequence Number*). There is some data retention involved though, so unless you add more logic to this, you will get a number representing the count of messages **currently** present in the hub, not the total since the creation, not the total left to process.

Update: here's the code showing a couple of methods to get the number of devices:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            string connString = "HostName=_______.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=_______;SharedAccessKey=_______";
            RegistryManager registry = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connString);

            // Method 1: using Device Twin
            string queryString = "SELECT COUNT() AS numberOfDevices FROM devices";
            IQuery query = registry.CreateQuery(queryString, 1);
            string json = (await query.GetNextAsJsonAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
            Dictionary<string, long> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, long>>(json);
            long count1 = data["numberOfDevices"];

            // Method 2: using Device Registry
            RegistryStatistics stats = await registry.GetRegistryStatisticsAsync();
            long count2 = stats.TotalDeviceCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very much useful and not giving anywhere though it is there into registryManager unable to find it easy!  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The values what you are interested are part of the [Azure IoT Hub metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-metrics). Basically you can obtained their:

- using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions)
- Adding the **diagnostic settings** for Azure IoT Hub and selecting one of the following destination for *AllMetrics*:

  1. to archiving in the **event-driven storage**. Using a subscriber such as an EventGridTrigger function with an input blob binding, the metrics can be queried within the function body.
  2. or pushing the metrics to streaming pipe via an **Event Hub** and using a stream analytics job for querying the metrics data.

Comment: but it does not contain device count , total message count etc

Comment: add to the url query string: metricnames=dailyMessageQuotaUsed,totalDeviceCount,connectedDeviceCount,...

Comment: list of IoT Hub metrics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-metrics#iot-hub-metrics-and-how-to-use-them

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge,

There is no direct method to actually get the **`total number of devices`**. Alternatively what you could do is to create a List and whenever you add Devices using **`AddDeviceAsync`** you should push the object to the list.

Same with Total number of messages, you should create your own way to keep the value updated.

The following code should help.

```
static async Task startClient(string IoTHub, string IoTDevicePrefix, int deviceNumber, string commonKey, int maxMessages, int messageDelaySeconds)
{
    allClientStarted++;
    runningDevices++;
    string connectionString = "HostName=" + IoTHub + ";DeviceId=" + IoTDevicePrefix + deviceNumber + ";SharedAccessKey=" + commonKey;
    DeviceClient device = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Mqtt);
    await device.OpenAsync();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int mycounter = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Device " + IoTDevicePrefix + deviceNumber + " started");

    while (mycounter <= maxMessages)
    {
        Thread.Sleep((messageDelaySeconds * 1000) + rnd.Next(1, 100));
        string message = "{ \'loadTest\':\'True\', 'sequenceNumber': " + mycounter + ", \'SubmitTime\': \'" + DateTime.UtcNow + "\', \'randomValue\':" + rnd.Next(1, 4096 * 4096) + " }";
        Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message IoTMessage = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        await device.SendEventAsync(IoTMessage);
        totalMessageSent++;
        mycounter++;
    }
    await device.CloseAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Device " + IoTDevicePrefix + deviceNumber + " ended");
    runningDevices--;
}

static void createDevices(int number)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
        Device mydevice = new Device(IoTDevicePrefix + i.ToString());
        mydevice.Authentication = new AuthenticationMechanism();
        mydevice.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey = commonKey;
        mydevice.Authentication.SymmetricKey.SecondaryKey = commonKey;
        try
        {
            registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(mydevice).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Adding device: " + IoTDevicePrefix + i.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Error adding device: " + IoTDevicePrefix + i.ToString() + " error: " + er.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

}
```